# Using PrettyFaces to Manage JSF Conversation ID Without It Being Included in the URL on Postback

Tags: jsf, cdi, prettyfaces, conversation-scope

I'm working on a JSF (JavaServer Faces) application and I've decided to use PrettyFaces as the URL rewriting library. I want to manage the conversation ID (cid) without it being included in the URL on postback. Is this achievable with PrettyFaces, and if so, how can I configure it properly?

Here are my current dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
    <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for JSF 2.x -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
    <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I've attempted to use the  element with onPostback="false" in the PrettyFaces configuration (pretty-config.xml), but the cid parameter is still visible in the URL on postback.

Any guidance or examples on how to properly configure PrettyFaces to handle the conversation ID without exposing it in the URL during postback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I've attempted to use the  element with onPostback="false" in the PrettyFaces configuration (pretty-config.xml), but the cid parameter is still visible in the URL on postback.